# Meteor production app fail to use Facebook's user_friends permission

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api, meteor

I have a mobile meteor app that uses the Facebook API and manage users authentication and sign-ups with the accounts-facebook package.

As long as I tested the app on meteor.com server and on local builds, the following code I provided successfully made the app use the Facebook's user_friends permission:

(That's under client/accounts.js)

```
Accounts.ui.config({
    requestPermissions: {
        facebook: ['user_friends']
    } 
});
```

However, since I deployed to production with mup, it seems like the user_friends permission doesn't take effect on Facebook itself anymore. Going through my MongoDB I can see that in the **db.meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration** collection the document for Facebook is:

```
{
  _id: "gCMyTCnTXq3RTPMWm",
  service: "facebook",
  appId: "*********", // censored
  loginStyle: "redirect",
  secret: "***************************", // censored
  requestPermissions: [
    "user_friends"
  ]
}
```

So the Meteor app knows that it should ask new users for this permission. Looking at my Facebook account application privacy settings I can see that in contrast with the non-production version I had, there is no "user friends" permission anymore for my app:

[image: Facebook no user friends permissions]

Since it's a mobile app, I tried editting the **accounts-config.js** to contain the permission as well:

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert(
    { service: "facebook" },
    {
        $set: {
            appId: "***********", // censored
            loginStyle: "redirect",
            secret: "********************************", // censored
            requestPermissions: ['user_friends']
        }
    }
);
```

Because I have customized login button I also do this while clicking it:

```
Meteor.loginWithFacebook(['user_friends']);
```

But had no success retrieving the permissions. Each time I did these changes I removed the users and the app from my Facebook account and tried again from a new Facebook login to avoid the fact that you can't override Facebook's permissions for exist user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appearently I used the Meteor.loginWith method wrong. It should get an options object that includes the requestPermissions string array like this, and the problem is solved:

```
        Meteor.loginWithFacebook({requestPermissions: ['user_friends']}, function(err){
            if (err){
                throw new Meteor.Error("facebook failure");
            }
        });
```